# only style for the drop down in bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have created a site in `Yii` and I have added bootstrap down on my web page, almost the whole look and feel of the site have changed. I want to get only the style for drop down menus is `bootstrap.css`. Is there any CSS available where there is only style for dropdown is available? So that I can customize the dropdown as I wish.
http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/dropdown.php i have completed the first drop down of this tutorial and i dont understand how can i customise it

Answer (score 0):

In customize section i think you can select exactly what you need in order to avoid adding unappropriate css or js file.

Comment: can you please explain,i didnt found any customisation section

Comment: If your interest in bootstrap is just using a few elements I think the  bootstrap customize section is what you are looking for.

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html is this the page you are suggesting me i would like to put a gradient color for the drop down menu is it possible,which all options i must select to get the drop down as a stylish one some thing like this ,forget about the hover effect ,i wanted it on click http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/animated-drop-down-css3

Comment: You can probably mix up bootstrap css with the one from your link. Looks like he achieved this stylish drop down using css only, it should be possible to make it work for the bootstrap component.